# Informatica - replace characters in target

Tags: java, xml, regex, oracle, informatica

Im working in a project which we create hundreds of xml's in informatica everyday, and all the data which is in the xml should be filtered, like removing all kind of special characters like * +.. You get the idea.

Adding regular expressions for every port is too complicated and not possible due the large amount of mapping we have.

I've added a custom property to the session XMLAnyTypeToString=Yes; and now i get some of the characters instead of &abcd, in their usual presentation (" + , ..).

I'm hoping for some custom property or change in XML target to remove these characters completely.
any idea?

Comment: are you looking to convert `&amp;` to `&` or `"` to `&quot;` , etc... ?

Comment: I'm looking into converting & $ % * @ to '' (empty string)

Comment: What about a script after the xml generation? Could be a simple perl oneliner. Not maybe the cleanest solution but superfast to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of String.replaceAll method:

> ```
>  String   replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) 
>           Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.
> ```

You can create a set of symbols you want to remove using regex, for example:

```
[*+"#$%&\(",.\)]
```

and then apply it to your string:

```
String myString = "this contains **symbols** like these $#%#$%";
String cleanedString = myString.replaceAll("[*+"#$%&]", "");
```

now you "cleanedString" is free of the symbols you've chosen.

By the way, you can test your regex expression in this excellent site:
http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html